# Unable to get HTML

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to open adfoc.us/504....9 link with httpwebrequest.
However it gives me no HTML code.

```
  try
    {
        req = WebRequest.Create(txtLink.Text);
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxies[0]);
        //req.Proxy = wp;

        WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(content);
        sr.Close();
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("URL should be in this format:\nhttp://www.google.com");
        return;
    }
```

If I use website like [google.com][1] - I get mbox with google html source.
If I use `adfoc.us/50....` link I get an empty string.

Where could be the problem?
Thank you.

EDIT: I resolved the problem by installing GeckoFx component.

Comment: because this link does not contain anything in its source

Comment: When How am I able to open it in my browser? I checked with tamper data and there are some redirects I think.

Comment: But still it doesn't work with httpwebrequest

Comment: Ok, I can see now that you're using a proxy. Does this happen when you   use direct connection?

Comment: Btw, why do I have the bad feeling that you're writing code to automatically hit ads with different proxies?

Comment: I commented the proxy until I can resolve this problem.

Comment: I will not use it for those reasons. I'm trying to learn how to use HttpWebRequest and came up with the problem where I am unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

If you can open the link in your browser and not from your code it could mean that adfoc.us blocks you because it can't find the useragent header. Try adding a useragent header that a browser uses.

Comment: That's not a real useragent string. Try this one: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`var req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) System.Net.WebRequest.Create("");
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`

and you can manual set `MaximumAutomaticRedirections`

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the `WebRequest`, add the following:

```
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
```

Seems like it doesn't like the default header. I got the above from Firefox request header.

Comment: I'll try this one. I did resolve the problem by installing Gecko browser and using it.